# Why `npm ls` does not return --all dependencies?

Tags: npm, ls

I'm looking into packages with vulnerabilities in our app. None of them was our direct dependency, but rather external packages dependencies.

First thing I did was trying to find which packages had those dependencies: `npm ls inflight`

```
└─┬ cspell@4.2.8
  └─┬ glob@7.2.3
    └── inflight@1.0.6
```

So, I can see that `inflight` is a dependency of `glob` which is a dependency of `cspell`.

The problem here, is that `glob` is used in a lot more packages than `cspell`. And if I run `npm ls glob`, I get a ton of packages that have `glob` as a dependency.

I actually deleted `cspell` and ran `npm ls inflight` again and the result now was:

```
└─┬ dot-object@2.1.4
  └─┬ glob@7.2.3
    └── inflight@1.0.6
```

So, why am I only getting 1 result from `npm ls inflight`? (I already tried --all, with same results)